# Cron Scheduler every day at 12 midnight

Tags: c#, cron, quartz-scheduler

I implement a schedule in MVC app to run job in every day midnight. This is the code.

```
    IScheduler sched = container.Resolve<IScheduler>();
    sched.JobFactory = new AutofacJobFactory(container);
    sched.Start();

    IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ProcessInvoiceJob>()
           .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
           .Build();

    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
        .WithCronSchedule("0 0 * * * ?")
        .Build();


    sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

I read few articles and it contains cron expression for 12 midnight is "0 0 * * * ?"

Eg : http://blog.bobcravens.com/2009/10/an-event-based-cron-scheduled-job-in-c/

The issue is my schedule executes in **every one hour**... How to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are telling it to execute on every hour, the correct CRON value for midnight only is `0 0 0 * * ?`

Edit: The resource you used is from 2009 so I can see how this would be wrong, for reference the current CRON is "Seconds Minutes Hours Day-of-Month Month Day-of-Week Year (optional field)"

Comment: Thanks for the reply XerShade. I'll change the expression as yours. Then I publish the project in server. It is passed few hours and seems it is stopped running the schedule once an hour. I'll let you know the status after one day.

Comment: Wow!!! This works fine. Thanks. But i wonder, why most of web sites show a wrong expression for 12 midnight. [link](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm) also shows a wrong expression.

Comment: Not sure, but as I said in the answer the correct format is "Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Day Number, Month, Day Names, Year (Optional)"